# Inconsistent results on Jupyer notebook and Intellij IDE: Python

Tags: python, intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to compute medcouple using robustats module in python.
https://github.com/FilippoBovo/robustats

The results on jupyter note book and IntelliJ Ide do not match.

Result on my **jupyter notebook:**

```
from robustats import medcouple
import numpy as np

x = np.array([9325.06, 6206.00, 10000.00, 9569.78])
print(medcouple(x))

-0.6442066420664204
```

Result on **IntelliJ Ide**

```
from robustats import medcouple
import numpy as np

x = np.array([9325.06, 6206.00, 10000.00, 9569.78])
print(medcouple(x))

nan
```

Has anyone came across this strange behaviour. Please do let me know if I have to change any setting on IDE.
I have made sure both are running against the same virtual env

Comment: it shouldn't be problem with IDEs. Check if you use the same Python version  - `sys.executable` - and the same modules versions.

Comment: both are pointing to the same version.

Comment: do you runs it on the same computer?

Comment: yes its on my desktop

Comment: When I tried on jupyter notebook in colab, it shows nan for the first time the code is executed, then on executing it again, it starts showing correct output. After restarting the runtime (session), I observed the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

it is not reproducible for me in 2021.1.3, robustats 0.1.7, Python 3.6, venv.

Could you please provide me with your setup details?

Please submit an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY
with logs folder zipped from ***Help | Collect logs and Diagnostic Data*** and a screencast presenting the behaviour.

Information on how to use YouTrack: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241135-How-to-follow-YouTrack-issues-and-receive-notifications

Comment: thanks for the response, unfortunately I cant send the logs of the current system. I will try to simulate it in my personal env and send them.